# How to update attribute value in CoreData after inserting it

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 attributes in CoreData Entity - `currentTime` and `artist`.

I want to update the `currentTime` without updating the `artist` attribute.

How to do that?

Comment: Try checking the 'artist' as soon as you fetch the object, before you make any changes to the 'currentTime'.  Maybe 'artist' had been saved to Core Data with a different value than you expected, and the value isn't changing when you update 'currentTime'.

Comment: it's value is ok on the fetch , because it's `CoreData` `TableView` so i can see it before change any values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fetch data object which you want to change.
2. Change currentTime property.
3. Save context.

This library could be usefull for you:

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: the fetch : `var object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(CurrentIndex!) as NSManagedObject` 
the change : `object.setValue(NSNumber.numberWithInt(3), forKey: “currentTime”)`
the save : `var error:NSError?  managedObjectContext?.save(&error)`

but if i do that the artist changed too i don’t know why , any suggestion why ?
and thanks in advance